# Passing float "byref" in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to pass a float "byref" to a method in objective C?  Here's an overview of what I've got:

method signature:

```
- (void) MyMethod: (float*) min max:(float*) max;
```

method:

```
- (void) MyMethod: (float*) min max:(float*) max
{
}
```

trying to invoke it:

```
float min1 = 0; float max1 = 0; 
[self MyMethod: min:&min1 max:&max1];
```

I get the following warning, and the code abends when trying to invoke MyMethod:

warning: 'MyClass' may not respond to '+MyMethod:min:max:'

Answer (score 3):

The signature for your method is declared as

```
- (void) MyMethod: (float*) min max:(float*) max
```

but you are calling it as

```
- MyMethod:min:max:
```

... which includes an extra 'min:' that's not in the declaration.

Try changing your calling code to

```
float min1 = 0; float max1 = 0; 
[self MyMethod:&min1 max:&max1];
```

and see if that improves things.

However, I see that your error message complains about the signature '+ MyMethod:min:max:', which also suggests you're trying to send the message to the *class* rather than an *instance* of the class; you will have to rectify that.

Finally, method selectors in Objective-C code usually start with a lower-case letter; you might want to read up on common [Objective-C naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html).

Comment: Problem solved. The extra "min" thing was a typo when I was retyping the error message.  The problem was actually (as you pointed out) that I was trying to invoke an instance method from a static/class method.  I'll read up on the naming conventions.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Apple's naming conventions for their Cocoa framework(s) are described <a href="http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html">here</a>.

Comment: ... or rather, here: http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html